# Is there a web-based tool to allow users to submit work items?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I'm aware of the stand-alone Work Item Manager from Telerik, and an outdated project on Codeplex that doesn't work with TFS 2010.

Are there any other tools that end-users to easily enter bug-reports and have them submitted to TFS as work items?  Something web-based would be preferrable, but i'd be ok with stand-alone.

WIM looks nice, but it's a little too much for end users to simply submit bugs.  And they're not in TFS and don't have Team Explorer.  So what other options are there?

Comment: You seriously don't know about Team Web Access?

Comment: I do now ;)  That's just what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like John said in his comments, there is Web Access (http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs/web) which you can use to report bugs. It is even possible to let external users to create new bugs and track them without needing a CAL (license): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668124.aspx

You can give users a url that opens a new bug form and prepopulates some values for them: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/05/06/Initial-values-in-a-work-item.aspx

Answer (score 3):

[Usersnap for TFS](https://usersnap.com/tfs) is exactly what you need.

Add Usersnap to your web project and [connect Usersnap with TFS](https://usersnap.com/connect/tfs) - you will get bug screenshots directly added to your TFS tickets as attachment:

[image]

Your users don't need to login and you don't need any CALs for them.

Full disclosure: I'm CTO and Co-Founder of [Usersnap](https://usersnap.com).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Team Project SharePoint site associated with your TFS project, you can even use the shipped and ready to use SharePoint Product Backlog webpart that comes with the Agile process template to enter new Bugs. Very low threshold and little pre-requisites for users.